# file upload in phonegap its destroy my session data of inappbrowser

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am using phonegap cordopva InAppBrowser to build an app. In InAppBrowser I called a page where its upload profile pic of user. In this if I used html file type field its not open gallery/camera. so I try to solve it by phonegap.
for this I detect url in phonegap and open gallery using below code:-

`pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);`

its working fine but when i used below code

`var ft = new FileTransfer();
 ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("MY-URL"), win, fail, options);`

it post my image on server but its destroy my session data of inappbrowser. please any one can explain why its destroying and how to fix this.

Comment: file an issue on issues.cordova.io